# Column not found 1054 error when defining laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have two tables: Order and Order_details. Between these two tables, there is a one-to-many relationship.

Order fields are:

- id_order
- invoice
- customer_id
- user_id
- total

Order_details fields:

- order_detail_id
- order_id
- product_id
- qty
- price

order_id is a foreign key which references to id_order on orders table

Order Model

```
 //
protected $primaryKey = 'id_order';
protected $fillable = [
    'invoice', 'customer_id', 'user_id', 'total'
];

public function order_detail()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order_detail::class);
}
```

Order_detail model

```
protected $primaryKey = 'order_detail_id';

protected $fillable = [
    'order_id', 'product_id', 'qty'
];

protected $guarded = [];

public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'order_id', 'order_detail_id');
}
```

When i tried to insert data to these table, i got an error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_id_order' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `order_details` (`product_id`, `qty`, `order_id_order`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (8, 1, 10, 2020-09-07 10:30:04, 2020-09-07 10:30:04))
```

Why laravel assume i have order_id_order field instead of order_id? And how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: It seems `Order` and `Order_Detail` both models code are same. In both model, `$primaryKey` is same `order_detail_id`. And another thing, put your controller code too, from where the data is being inserted.

Comment: You should not specify both `$fillable` and `$guarded` at the same time. Use one OR the other.

Comment: I also recommend that you follow Laravel naming conventions, so that the primary key is just `id`.  If you follow the Laravel naming convention with table-names and primary-keys, you do not have to specify any arguments to `belongsTo()` other than the related model-class. It will save you a lot of headache, I can nearly guarantee it.

Comment: @GhanuBha sorry, it was a mistake. I updated Order Model

Comment: In eloquent relationship, if we will not pass argument of `foreign_key` and `loca_key` then laravel auto detect and postfix `_id` on `primaryKey`. So, here, in `Order` model, you have to pass other 2 argumets that you have passed in `belongsTo` relationship. Add this  `'order_id', 'order_detail_id'` in `HasMany` relationship and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, in your question, `orders` table is the parent table and `order_details` is the child table. So one order can have many order details. So there is `one-to-many` relationship.

In `Order.php` i.e order model, you need to have forward relation, with proper mapping with the primary key and foreign key.

```
public function orderDetails()
{
    #1st arg is related model,
    #2nd arg is related column of order_details table
    #3rd arg is related column of orders table
    return $this->hasMany(OrderDetail::class, 'order_id', 'order_id');
}
```

Now coming to `OrderDetail.php` i.e. order_detail model, you need to have inverse relation as given below.

```
public function order()
{
    #1st arg is related model,
    #2nd arg is related column of orders table
    #3rd arg is related column of order_details table
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'order_id', 'order_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define Foreign Key on both functions

Order Model

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'order_id');
}
```

Orderdetail Model

```
public function order_detail()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order_detail::class,'order_id');
}
```